# How to create custom notification for ossec

Tags: ossec

I am installing OSSEC for secure our servers, and I want to use slack instead of email for notification.

Is there a way to send alerts via slack?  Is there any way to add another notification system besides email?

I think i can use active response for that; is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

i found, that you can send ossec notification with active responces: look at this [example](http://dcid.me/blog/2009/04/ossec-to-twitter/) and this [ossec-tweeter.sh](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/blob/master/active-response/ossec-tweeter.sh)